# Use <div>s inside $outputs

Tags: php, html, css, json, html-framework-7

I've just started php and I wanted to do something with json too.

It's kinda hard to explain, but I want it so when it finds app_name in the json file, it will create a div and place it in that div

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://dwiftejb.github.io/repo.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $output ="<ul>";
    foreach($json['apps'] as $app){
        $output ="<h1>".$app['app_name']."</h1>";
        echo $output;
        $output ="<li>".$app['label']."</li>";
        echo $output;
    }
    $output .= "</ul>";
?>
```

and I want to get these div's inside of it:

```
<div class="card card-outline">
  <div class="card-content card-content-padding">TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Here's what the div looks like:

[image: div looks like]

Comment: Where does that DIV go with respect to the LI?

Comment: I'm honestly clueless with php, I'm wondering how to use quotes inside of quotes.

Comment: Use single quotes inside double quotes, or vice versa, or escape the quotes.

Comment: Can I use single quotes in the $output bit of my code?

Comment: Sure, why not? HTML allows either single or double quotes around attributes. `<div class='card card-outline'>`

Comment: Your question is still unclear about how you want the resulting HTML to look. Can you show the entire desired result including the`<ul>`, `<h1>`, and `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using quotes inside of quotes, you can use single ' and double ".

```
   echo "<div class='card card-outline'><div class='card-content card-content-padding'>{$app["label"]}</div></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I'm just waiting for stack overflow to allow me to actually say it worked.